# How to parse and categorize JSON response from AlamoFire in xcode

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, http

I am trying to get NBA standings from this website https://erikberg.com/api
To do this, I am using AlmoFire to make a Get request:

`Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://erikberg.com/nba/standings.json")
            .responseJSON { response in
                    print(response.2.value)
}`

What this is returning is a response array with a NSURLRequest at index 0, an NSHTTPURLResponse at index 1, and a result of type AnyObject at index 2. The AnyObject, when printed, results in this (I'm only showing one team because the array is very long):

`Optional({
    standing =     (
                {
            "away_lost" = 14;
            "away_won" = 21;
            conference = EAST;
            "conference_lost" = 13;
            "conference_won" = 29;
            division = CEN;
            "first_name" = Cleveland;
            "games_back" = 0;
            "games_played" = 71;
            "home_lost" = 6;
            "home_won" = 30;
            "last_five" = "4-1";
            "last_name" = Cavaliers;
            "last_ten" = "7-3";
            lost = 20;
            "ordinal_rank" = 1st;
            "playoff_seed" = 1;
            "point_differential" = 437;
            "point_differential_per_game" = "6.2";
            "points_against" = 6948;
            "points_allowed_per_game" = "97.9";
            "points_for" = 7385;
            "points_scored_per_game" = "104.0";
            rank = 1;
            streak = W2;
            "streak_total" = 2;
            "streak_type" = win;
            "team_id" = "cleveland-cavaliers";
            "win_percentage" = ".718";
            won = 51;
        },exc...`

I would like to know how I can parse this data so I can extract and categorize each team based on their standings.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) to parse JSON. Make a Standing class which contains all the JSON to object mapping code.

```
class Standing: Mappable {
    var awayLost: Int?
    var awayWon: Int?
    .....      // Define all variables
    required init?(_ map: Map) {}

    // This function is used to map all variables to corresponding JSON strings
    func mapping(map: Map) {      
         awayLost <- map["away_lost"]
         awayWon <- map["away_won"]
         ... 
    }
```

Similarly, make a parent class to hold array of standing.

```
class ParentJson: Mappable {
    var standingsDate: String?
    var standing: [Standing]
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    standing <- map["standing"]
}
```

And then in your alamofire response, map the corresponding class

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://erikberg.com/nba/standings.json")
        .responseJSON { response in
             let parentJson = Mapper<ParentJson>().map(response.2.value)
             let standingsArray: [Standing] = parentJson.standing
```

standingArray will now have all the data required to categorize.

Comment: I did exactly what you did, but I got an error: Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11, and this is causing xcode to crash

Comment: I figured out how to get rid of the error, but when I try to print out the seed or wins of a team, the output is empty; all there is is (llbd). Here is my code

`Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://erikberg.com/nba/standings.json")
            .responseJSON { response in
                let parentJson = Mapper<Standings>().map(response.2.value)
              let standingsArray: [Team] = parentJson!.standing!
                let team = Mapper<Team>().map(standingsArray[0])
                print(team?.seed)
                           }
`

Comment: you can just access seed by calling standingsArray[0].playoffSeed. I am assuming that you have mapped values correctly.  In your Standing class, you should have mapped it as `playoffSeed <- map["playoff_seed"]` where playoffSeed is an integer

Comment: I have gotten it to work, but when i print the value of playoffSeed, it returns Optional(seed) rather than just the seed

Answer (score -1):

I use the [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) package for all things JSON related. Then, you can use this idiom

```
.responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .Success:
        if let value = response.result.value {
            let json = JSON(value)
            if let datum = json["field"].string { // Depending on expected type; see docs

            }

     case .Failure(let error):
         print(error)
     }
```